# Uniqueness of adjoint functors up to isomorphism

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, natural-transformations

$\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}$Suppose we are given functors $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{D}$ and $G,G':\mathcal{D}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ such that $G$ and $G'$ are both right adjoint to $F$. To show that $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic, we wish to come up with a natural isomorphism between the two functors. This is how Awodey does it:

> For any $D\in\mathcal{D}$ and any $C\in\mathcal{C}$, we have that $\Hom(C,GD)\cong \Hom(FC,D)\cong \Hom(C,G'D)$ simply using the hom-set definition of adjunctions. By the Yoneda principle, this means that $GD\cong G'D$ for all $D\in\mathcal{D}$.

Awodey then states that

> But this isomorphism is natural in $D$,  **again by adjointness**.

I dont' quite understand how the naturality follows from adjointness. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: the final click in my head came while reading theorem 165 in Category TheoryA Gentle Introduction by Peter Smith https://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/GentleIntro.pdf

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The bijection $\hom(C,GD) \cong \hom(C,G'D)$ is natural in $C$, thus it is induced by an isomorphism $GD \cong G'D$ (Yoneda Lemma). But it is also natural in $D$, and since the Yoneda embedding is faithful, this means that $GD \cong G'D$ is natural in $D$. More details:

If $D \to E$ is a morphism, then

$\begin{array}{ccc} GD & \rightarrow & G'D \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ GE & \rightarrow & G'E \end{array}$

commutes iff for every $C$ the diagram

$\begin{array}{ccc} \hom(C,GD) & \rightarrow & \hom(C,G'D) \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \hom(C,GE) & \rightarrow & \hom(C,G'E) \end{array}$

commutes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear-cut answer!

Comment: How do you use faithtfulness of the Yoneda embedding to claims that naturality in $D$ implies that $G\cong G'$? (I can show it explicitly with diagrams after having concluded that $GD\cong G'D$ for each $D$ with Yoneda, because I know how this isomorphism looks like in terms of the natural isomorphism between $\hom(-,GD)$ and $\hom(-,G'D)$, but I'm curious if there is a short-cut)

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be one of those cases where the proof from scratch is the easy, and you don't need to know (explictly) anything about Yoneda.

1). You know there is a natural isomorphism given by $\varphi_{A,D} :$hom$(A,GD)\rightarrow $hom$(A,G'D)$

2). Set $A=GD$, $\varphi _{GD,D}(1 _{GD})=\tau _{D}$. Then, by what follows, the $\tau _{D}$ are the components of the required natural isomorphism $G\overset{\cdot }{\rightarrow}G'$

3) Write

\begin{array}{ccc} \hom(GD,GD) & \rightarrow & \hom(GD,G'D) \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \hom(GD,GD_{1}) & \rightarrow & \hom(GD,G'D_{1} ) \end{array}
Then if $f:D\rightarrow D_{1}$, follow $1_{GD}$ around the square. This gives $G'f\circ \tau _{D}=\varphi _{GD,D_{1}}(Gf)$.

4). Write \begin{array}{ccc} \hom(GD_{1},GD_{1}) & \rightarrow & \hom(GD_{1},G'D_{1}) \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow \\ \hom(GD,GD_{1}) & \rightarrow & \hom(GD,G'D_{1} ) \end{array}

and follow $1_{GD_{1}}$ around the square. This gives $\varphi _{GD,D_{1}}(Gf)= \tau _{D_{1}}\circ Gf$

5). Combining the previous two items, you get $G'f\circ \tau _{D}=\tau _{D_{1}}\circ Gf$, so $\tau $ is a natural transformation. Now, since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, natural in $A$ and $D$, for each $D$,  $\varphi _{GD,D}(1 _{GD})=\tau_{D}$ is an isomorphism, which implies $\tau $ itself is.

Comment: I'm confused by the last sentence. I don't see how $\varphi$ being an isomorphism implies that $\tau_D$ is.

Comment: Can we still use the same $f:D\rightarrow D_1$ in step (4)?

Comment: @uk62116 I don't see why not

Comment: @prt13463 Define $\lambda_D = \varphi^{-1}_{G'D,D}(1_{G'D})$, which is an arrow $G'D\to GD$. Analogously as above you can prove that this is a natural transformation.
To prove that $\tau_D\circ \lambda_D = 1_{G'D}$, use naturality of $\varphi$:
$ \varphi_{G'D, D} \circ \lambda_D^* = \lambda_D^* \circ \varphi_{GD, D}$. Apply both sides to $1_{GD}$. Going one direction you get $\tau_D\circ \lambda_D$. The other direction gives $\varphi_{G'D,D}(\lambda_D) = 1_{G'D}$. (The other composition equals the identity using similar argument).

Answer (score 3):

We actually have a composite of *natural* isomorphisms $\tau:\hom(\bullet,G\bullet)\to \hom(F\bullet,\bullet)\to \hom(\bullet,G'\bullet)$.

In more details, $\tau$ has components $\tau_{C,D}:\hom(C,GD)\to\hom(C,G'D)$ satisfying the naturality condition: for arrows $\gamma:C_1\to C$, $\ \delta:D\to D_1\,$  and $\, f:C\to GD$ we have
$$\tau(G\delta\circ f\circ\gamma)=G'\delta\circ\tau(f)\circ\gamma\,. $$
Now applying the Yoneda lemma basically means to consider the case when $C=GD$ and apply $\tau$ to $1_{GD}$. It leads to a $GD\to G'D$ arrow, verify (using the above equation) that it's natural in $D$, and find its inverse (e.g. by applying the same to $C=G'D$ and $\tau^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not quite sure how that implies that the isomorphism $GD\cong G'D$ is natural.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that I answer precisely on your question, but I want to share my idea.

Let's view the category $C$ as a full subcategory of its presheaves (image of the Yoneda embedding $C\to\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}$).

Adjunction gives you a natural isomorphism $\hom_C(C,G(D))\to \hom_C(C,G'(D))$, which is actually a natural isomorphism between the following two functors:
$$
X=(\hom_C\circ(I_{C^{op}}\times G))\colon C^{op}\times D\to\mathbf{Set};
$$
$$
Y=(\hom_C\circ(I_{C^{op}}\times G'))\colon C^{op}\times D\to\mathbf{Set},
$$
which are objects in the category $\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}\times D}$. Consider an exponential functor:
$$
E\colon\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}\times D}\to(\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}})^D
$$
So we have two isomorphic functors $E(X),E(Y)\colon D\to\mathbf{Set}^{C^{op}}$. It's easy to check that their images are in $C$, and constriction on $C$ yields $E(X)|_C=G, E(Y)|_{C}=G'$. Thus, the natural isomorphism between $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ induce a natural isomorphism between $G$ and $G'$.

Comment: I think this is a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

A very compact proof:

We have $\text{Hom}(\cdot,G\cdot)\cong\text{Hom}(\cdot,G'\cdot)$ in $[{\cal C}^\text{op}\times{\cal D},\text{Set}]$ and want to show $G\cong G'$.

The Yoneda embedding $y:{\cal C}\rightarrow[{\cal C}^\text{op},\text{Set}]$ is full and faithfull, this property transmits to its pushforward $y_*:[{\cal D},{\cal C}]\rightarrow[{\cal D},[{\cal C}^\text{op},\text{Set}]]\cong[{\cal C}^\text{op}\times{\cal D},\text{Set}]$, which means $G\cong G'$ iff $y_*G\cong y_*G'$.  But the last equation is exactly our premise when written out.