# How unique is the exponential of sets?

Tags: category-theory

Firstly I would like to thank everyone in this site for their valuable help. You have helped me a lot understanding the idea of an exponential.

I would like to ask a final question that is the last piece of the puzzle for me. It is clear that the function set $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ is the exponential (by which I mean the categorical exponential, as defined by the universal property of the evaluation map) of the sets $X$ and $Y$ in the category of sets. What does the word "is" mean in the previous sentence? What kind of uniqueness exists here? Are all sets that are isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ also exponentials of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Yes, any object isomorphic to "the" exponential for two objects is as good as their exponential.

Comment: I beg to differ, @MaliceVidrine, see the answer by Hurkyl.

Comment: @k.stm how are the two answers different? Don't they both say that the exponential is unique up to bijection?...

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused here. Hurkyl explains the details behind my claim above...

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear of me: The essential point is that any exponential object consists of two informations: The object itself and the evaluation map. For instance, $ℕ^ℕ$ is isomorphic to $ℝ$ in the category of sets, yet that doesn’t make $ℝ$ an exponential object. You need to give the evaluation map in both cases and only for $ℕ^ℕ$ there is an obvious choice which is why we don’t state it explicitly. If that is what you meant @MaliceVidrine, I apologize. Although I still think your comment misses the essential point of the issue.

Comment: It would be wrong or at the very least very careless to state that any set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ is an exponential object for $ℕ$ to $ℕ$. It’s like stating that any set with cardinalty $6$ is a cyclic group (which of course can go wrong if you choose the wrong multiplication).

Comment: @k.stm Yeah, and thanks for the clarification. What is the most we can say is, I believe, what I wrote in Hurkyl's answer below. Can we agree on that? =)

Comment: Well, it was a comment and not an answer because I was making no pretense of completeness. However, it doesn't make any sense to say *of an object* that it's an exponential except to say that there exists a suite of arrows to and fro that object with the right property; and the question makes no sense except to ask whether an isomorphism with a known exponential allows us to form the appropriate suite of arrows on the isomorphic object, to which the answer is affirmative. Issues of "canonicity" or other structures supported by an object are beside the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget that the exponential consists of an object $Y^X$ *and* an evaluation map $e : Y^X \times X \to Y$.

Every isomorphism $i : Y^X \to Z$ lets us construct another exponential whose object is $Z$ and whose evaluation map is $e \circ (i^{-1} \times 1_X)$. Every other exponential is of this form.

In fact, one can give a suitable definition of a morphism of exponentials, and all exponentials are isomorphic.

(technically, we should be allowing for the choice of product to vary too)

Comment: Not merely isomorphic but _uniquely_ so.

Comment: Ok. So, please let me sum it up: if for a set $A$ there exists a function $\epsilon:S\times X\to Y$ such that for every set $Z$ and every function $g:Z\times X\to Y$ there is a unique function $f:Z\to S$ such that $g=\epsilon\circ (f\times 1_X)$, then $S$ is isomorphic to $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Excuse me, by $A$ I mean $S$.

Comment: Yes. (assuming you've cited the definition correctly)

Comment: So what is, exactly, the description of the exponential of sets $X$ and $Y$, given the function set $Y^X$ and the evaluation map $e$? If I understand what you are saying, it is not the collection of all sets that are isomorphic to $Y^X$. I see this, because as @k.stm says above, $\mathbb{R}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbf{Set}$, but it is not an exponential for the sets $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$. How do you obtain, then, their complete classification? They are pairs $(T,e_T)$ that have what property, given the pair $(Y^X,e)$? Thank you very much!

Comment: I already gave the classification in my answer; e.g. for any bijection $i : \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{N}^{\mathbf{N}}$, the pair $(\mathbf{R}, e \circ (i \times 1_X))$ *is* an exponential of $\mathbf{N}$ and $\mathbf{N}$. @k.stm: wasn't trying to say that $\mathbf{R}$ isn't (the object of an) exponential -- he was trying to say that you haven't specified an exponential unless you also give the evaluation map.

Comment: Is this a classification? For every isomorphism you get one, but how do you prove that these are all the exponentials you can have?...

Comment: The isomorphism comes directly from the universal property. If $(E, e')$ is another exponential, then in particular $e'$ is a map from $E \times X \to Y$....

Answer (score 2):

For a set $S$, the exponentiaton $(-)^S$ is right adjoint to $- \times S$.

It is a direct consequence of Yoneda's lemma that adjoints are unique up to isomorphism. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/389947/73610).