# Interesting example of more than one adjunction between a pair of adjoint functors?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $ F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D} $, and $G : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C} $ is a pair of adjoint functors with an adjunction $\alpha : Hom (FX,Y) \simeq Hom(X,GY)$.
Now in principle there could be more than one adjunction between the two functors $F,G$. Are there any common interesting examples where this situation arises ?

Comment: The adjunction is essentially unique, meaning that given two such, say $\alpha$, $\alpha'$, there will be a a natural isomorphism $\rho : G \to G$, such that $\alpha' = \rho_\ast \circ \alpha$. See the question [uniqueness of adjoint functors up to isomrphism](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389933/uniqueness-of-adjoint-functors-up-to-isomorphism), for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The morphism is **unique up to an isomorphism**; hence the answer to your question is *yes* and *no*.

Since there is a **unique** morphism that can "stand in" for any other, the other isomorphic copies (equivalence classes if you will) are irrelevant; the canonical copy carries all the information you need, hence the unique designation, hence a *no* answer.

But the fact remains that by definition, there are still **isomorphic** adjunctions and thus there are in fact other adjunctions.  Further, by the Univalent Foundation and it's "equality is isomorphic to isomorphism" theorem, you are allowed to work within these copies instead of just with the equivalence class of copies; with a particular adjunction instead of just with it's categorically canonical version.  Hence, a *yes* answer

Comment: Thanks. I did not understand the statement "equality is isomorphic to isomorphism", as I have not studied Univalent foundations. Could you please advise some reference where I can understand that statement ? Thanks

Comment: It would be my pleasure; this is "the book"; right off the bat on page six is the quote to which I refer https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/